# list all computers except domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I'd like to get the list of all computers within a domain. Searching on google I've found

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(objectClass=Computer)" -attr name -l -d my.domain > c:\computers.txt
```

Is there any way to have the same result excluding domain controller(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typically omit the `-d my.domain` portion if running the query on any domain computer.  The LDAP filter `(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192)` returns all Domain Controllers, negating the filter will exclude DCs.

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter  "&(objectCategory=computer)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192)" -attr name -l > c:\computers.without.dcs.txt
```

Detailed description of the *UserAccountControl* attribute is [available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832%28VS.85%29.aspx) as well as [Microsoft's support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PowerShell to accomplish this, install the [Quest PowerShell Commands for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) on a computer with PowerShell version 2 and issue the following command.

`Get-QADComputer | ?{$_.ComputerRole -ne 'DomainController'} | Select Name | Export-Csv Without-DCs.csv`

This will give you a CSV file in the current directory with all computers except Domain Controllers.